# git shows files as modified right after a clone

Tags: git

I cloned a repo and following the clone I have a bunch of files (but not all) marked as modified (according to git status).

A `git diff` on any of the files shows that all lines will be deleted and all lines will be added (but no differences - all the lines are identical)

If I do `git diff --ignore-all-space` it shows no differences.
Which leads me to believe it's a line endings issue.

But when I open the files in, say NotePad++, I see the correct CRLF characters at the end of each line (I am in a Windows env so I want CRLF at repo level and local level).

In my `.gitattributes` file I have an entry (I don't want git to do anything with my files):

`* -text`

So why are some files appearing as modified ?

Comment: The original files used Unix newlines, not DOS newlines, and the default behavior of Git is to use the native format when checking out a file.

Comment: The `* -text` *should* override the CRLF modifications that Git might do. However, if you want to work with text files that Git will store as newline-only and your computer will see as CRLF, you could use `* text eol=crlf` or `* text` and let Git use the "native" (CRLF) endings. Or you can get pick-and-choose-y. Why `* -text` is behaving this way is a mystery though.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting the config to handle this for you.  This should autoconvert it so handles the translation between windows and unix without it looking like every file is touched.

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

[Here](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings) is documentation that explains it in detail.